InfinityFree Hosting Issue: InvalidArgumentException view not found
Website URL: http://littlesmartdaycare.infinityfreeapp.com/
I am currently hosting my website on IF(infinityfree) subdomain.

This is the error I am running into. I googled and asked ChatGPT, all suggested that my controller is unable to locate my blade view, index.blade.php. However, I tested in my local environment and it ran successfully, then I uploaded my folder as is to IF filemanager via WinSCP. I understand that IF lack the command CLI to run compile & caching, so I did all that in my local machine then upload the updated files(Please let me know if this is incorrect, I am still inexperienced on this subject).
I will provide as much relevant code snippet as I believe so below:
index.blade.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Little Smart Day Care Centre</title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css">
    @include('components.header')

    <script src="https://code.tidio.co/0i12wozmwajexcywukm95pjuqf8tphpx.js" async></script>
</head>

<body>
    @include('components.navbar')

    <section>
        @include('components.alert_notification')

        @auth
            <h1>Welcome, {{ Auth::user()->name }}.</h1>
        @else
            <h1>小聪明安亲班 Little Smart Day Care Centre</h1>
        @endauth
        <br>

        <div class="center">
            <h2>Announcement</h2>

            @if ($posts->isEmpty())
                @include('components.no_records')
            @else
                @foreach ($posts as $post)
                <section>
                    <p>{{ $post->createdtime->format('Y-m-d H:i') }}</p>
                    @if (!empty($post->images))
                        <div class="slick-carousel">
                            @foreach ($post->images as $image)
                                <div><img src="{{ asset('storage/uploads/' . $image) }}" alt="{{ $post->title }}" /></div>
                            @endforeach
                        </div>
                    @endif
                    <h3>{{ $post->title }}</h3>
                    @if ($post->description)
                        {!! $post->description !!}
                    @endif
                </section>
                <br>
                @endforeach

                <nav aria-label="Page navigation">
                {{ $posts->links('pagination::bootstrap-4') }}
                </nav>
            @endif
        </div>
    </section>

    @include('components.send_feedback')
    @include('components.footer')

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.slick-carousel').slick({
                dots: true,
                adaptiveHeight: true,
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>

PostController.php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Post;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * (CRUD read)
     * Display a listing of the resource, exclusive for announcement page.
     *
     * Retrieves all records from 'posts' table, split into several pages,
     * Decode JSON data for 'posts.images', which converts JSON string to
     * PHP array. Pass final data to blade view.
     */
    public function indexHome()
    {
        // Cut-off point for page nav btn is 15 pages (ellipsis will appear)
        $posts = Post::orderBy('createdtime', 'desc')->paginate(5); // number of records per page

        $posts->getCollection()->transform(function ($post) {
            $post->images = json_decode($post->images);
            return $post;
        });

        // pass an empty variable
        // $posts = collect();

        return view('index', compact('posts'));
    }
}

web.php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\PostController;
use App\Http\Middleware\CheckSessionTimeout;

Route::middleware([CheckSessionTimeout::class])->group(function () {

    Route::get('/', [PostController::class, 'indexHome']
    )->name('index');

});

Extra Question: have you check your .env config and recache your config?
Answer: I did check .env as ChatGPT suggested before, as shown here
.env
APP_NAME="Little Smart Day Care Centre"
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:D02P6ouibQnY+YdnpdMgDxYVpD8e6TP9ls/NmeL+SeA=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_TIMEZONE=UTC
APP_URL=http://littlesmartdaycare.infinityfreeapp.com

APP_LOCALE=en
APP_FALLBACK_LOCALE=en
APP_FAKER_LOCALE=en_US

APP_MAINTENANCE_DRIVER=file
APP_MAINTENANCE_STORE=database

BCRYPT_ROUNDS=12

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_STACK=single
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=sql110.infinityfree.com
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=if0_37135633_littlesmartdb
DB_USERNAME=if0_37135633
DB_PASSWORD=**removed to protect privacy**

SESSION_DRIVER=database
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_ENCRYPT=false
SESSION_PATH=/
SESSION_DOMAIN=.littlesmartdaycare.infinityfreeapp.com

BROADCAST_CONNECTION=log
FILESYSTEM_DISK=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database

CACHE_STORE=database
CACHE_PREFIX=

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_CLIENT=phpredis
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=sandbox.smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=a8170dee1ad9f9
MAIL_PASSWORD=**removed to protect privacy**
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="littlesmartdaycare@gmail.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false

VITE_APP_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

On a side note, the reason I keep my env as local is due to my settings here:
AppServiceProvider.php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     */
    public function register(): void
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
        // Convert HTTP to HTTPS when
        // [.env] file [APP_ENV] variable = "production"
        if ($this->app->environment('production')) {
            URL::forceScheme('https');
        }
    }
}

And for people who want me to double check my uploaded directory, here are my screenshots:



These are all the relevant info I can think of, please let me know how can I assist in pointing out the root cause. Thank you.

Run these command php artisan config:cache & php artisan config:clear and check again

Unrelated: instead of manually transforming json to array: $post->images = json_decode($post->images);, within casts method within your Post model file specify column: images name to deserialize

@Subha infinityfree basic free plan doesnt have access to command panel, what I did is to locally run your suggested commands, then upload the changed files to host folders as "manual clear cache". I have attempted this, but it shows no result. Thanks for your idea still!

@Derrick, Then there might be some issue you file access permissions in the resources/views/ folder. Check and confirm it whether server has access to that file.

@Subha based on my directory screenshots, resources/views/ rxxr-xr-x permission, which is equivalent to 755. Each file within that has rw-r--r-- permission, which is equivalent to 644. I have not changed these settings. Hope that clarifies my context!

I finally traced the issue from the new observation.
Source issue: /htdocs/bootstrap/cache/config.php

Even though I manually cached & updated my files, this particular file doesn't update for the most part, for the code block in question here:

'view' => 
  array (
    'paths' => 
      array (
        0 => 'C:\\laravel_little_smart_website\\resources\\views',
      ),
    'compiled' => 'C:\\laravel_little_smart_website\\storage\\framework\\views',
  ),

They are all pointing to my local setup, so after I change it to point to host folder:
'view' => 
  array (
    'paths' => 
      array (
        0 => '/home/vol14_2/infinityfree.com/if0_37135633/htdocs/resources/views',
      ),
    'compiled' => '/home/vol14_2/infinityfree.com/if0_37135633/htdocs/storage/framework/views',
  ),

It finally works. Infinityfree unable to access command panel is really tedious.
